# C++ *string convert to string

Tags: c++, string

I've seen a code and there was string* name. Isn't it wrong? I mean string name is already creating a vector of characters, what would there be string* ? Thank you!

Comment: It's a pointer to string... Could you please show us the code?

Answer (score 2):

It would be something like

```
string *xyz = new string (...)
```

which is a string pointer.
Can you please post the part of a code here of what you saw/made.